# Parse HTTP requests and responses from text file in Go

Tags: go

Given the following file which holds a HTTP pipelined stream of HTTP requests and HTTP responses.

**How can I parse this file into my `stream` variable?**

```
type Connection struct{
   Request *http.Request
   Response *http.Response
}
stream := make([]Connection, 0)
```

The raw file:

```
GET /ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: archive.ubuntu.com
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 26 Nov 2015 18:26:36 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 311
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at archive.ubuntu.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
GET /ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: archive.ubuntu.com
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 26 Nov 2015 18:26:37 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Thu, 26 Nov 2015 18:03:00 GMT
ETag: "fbb7-5257562a5fd00"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 64439
Cache-Control: max-age=382, proxy-revalidate
Expires: Thu, 26 Nov 2015 18:33:00 GMT

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA512

Origin: Ubuntu
Label: Ubuntu
Suite: trusty-updates
Version: 14.04
Codename: trusty
[... truncated by author]
```

I know there is [http.ReadRequest](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ReadRequest). What about the Response? Any ideas/feedback/thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's actually pretty straightforward:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "os"
)

type Connection struct {
    Request  *http.Request
    Response *http.Response
}

func ReadHTTPFromFile(r io.Reader) ([]Connection, error) {
    buf := bufio.NewReader(r)
    stream := make([]Connection, 0)

    for {
        req, err := http.ReadRequest(buf)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            return stream, err
        }

        resp, err := http.ReadResponse(buf, req)
        if err != nil {
            return stream, err
        }

        //save response body
        b := new(bytes.Buffer)
        io.Copy(b, resp.Body)
        resp.Body.Close()
        resp.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(b)

        stream = append(stream, Connection{Request: req, Response: resp})
    }
    return stream, nil

}
func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("/tmp/test.http")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    stream, err := ReadHTTPFromFile(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    for _, c := range stream {
        b, err := httputil.DumpRequest(c.Request, true)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(string(b))
        b, err = httputil.DumpResponse(c.Response, true)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(string(b))
    }
}
```

A few notes:

- There are [`http.ReadRequest`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ReadRequest) and [`http.ReadResponse`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ReadResponse)
- `http.ReadRequest` and `http.ReadResponse` can be called over and over again on the same `bufio.Reader` until `EOF` and it will "just work"

  - "just working" depends on the Content-Length header being present and correct, so reading the body will place the Reader at the start of the next request/response
  - [Read the code](https://golang.org/src/net/http/transfer.go#L305) to understand exactly what will work and what won't
- `resp.Body` must be `Close`ed per the docs, so we have to copy it to another buffer to keep it
- Using your example data (modifying Content-Length to match your truncation), this code will output the same Requests and Responses as given
- `httputil.DumpRequest` and `httputil.DumpResponse` won't necessarily dump the HTTP headers in the same order as the input file, so don't expect a `diff` to be perfect

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much. I must have missed the http.ReadResponse func. And I love the fact that calling the read func over and over again just works!

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised it worked also. But it's bascially working off Content-Length so it makes sense. Would probably be better if you had some kind of delimiter between requests/responses and used something like `io.LimitedReader` to make sure you don't get thrown off by a bad HTTP response.

Comment: I keep getting 'unexpected EOF'

Comment: Such solution won't work with HTTP/2, `ReadResponse` fails with "malformed HTTP version HTTP/2"

Comment: @zzell seems related to [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18464)

Comment: The answer is great! I just want to add that in my case it was needed to add one more line break to the end of the request text representation/file

Comment: This works great for GET requests. How would I go about modifying it to support POST, PUT etc.? Tried the reading post data in the request by calling req.ParseForm. Even after reading the post body using ParseForm, looks like the reader cursor hasn't moved. Because, when I try to read the response, after the parseform call, it complains about a malformed response line and errors out with the req. body line.

Comment: If the request has a body, it also needs a content-length header so ReadRequest knows how far to read. You'll also need to copy the request body into a buffer and replace it like the above code does for the response. (four lines below "//save response body")