# How to efficiently store html response to a file in golang

Tags: go, web-crawler, httprequest

I'm trying to build a crawler in Golang. I'm using `net/http` library to download the html file from url. I'm trying to save `http.resp` and `http.Header` into file.

How to convert these two file from their respective format into string so that, it could be written to a text file.

I also see a question asked earlier on parsing a stored html response file.  [Parse HTTP requests and responses from text file in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33963467/parse-http-requests-and-responses-from-text-file-in-go?rq=1) . Is there any way to save the url response in this format.

Comment: see also [`http.Response.Write`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response.Write) method, which is used by [`httputil.DumpResponse`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpResponse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** Thanks to @JimB for pointing to the *http.Response.Write* method which makes this a lot easier than I proposed in the beginning:

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://google.com/")

if err != nil{
    log.Panic(err)
}

f, err := os.Create("output.txt")
defer f.Close()

resp.Write(f)
```

*This was my first Answer*

You could do something like this:

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://google.com/")

body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

// write whole the body
err = ioutil.WriteFile("body.txt", body, 0644)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

*This was the edit to my first answer:*

Thanks to @Hector Correa who added the header part. Here is a more comprehensive snippet, targeting your whole question. This writes header followed by the body of the request to output.txt

```
//get the response
resp, err := http.Get("http://google.com/")

//body
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

//header
var header string
for h, v := range resp.Header {
    for _, v := range v {
        header += fmt.Sprintf("%s %s \n", h, v)
    }
}

//append all to one slice
var write []byte
write = append(write, []byte(header)...)
write = append(write, body...)

//write it to a file
err = ioutil.WriteFile("output.txt", write, 0644)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Or you could get all the correct information using the [`http.Response.Write`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response.Write) method, which is used by [`httputil.DumpResponse`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpResponse)

Comment: thanks @JimB, didn't know about this! Edited the snippet.

Answer (score 5):

Go has an httputil package with a response dump.
https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpResponse.
The second argument of response dump is a bool of whether or not to include the body. So if you want to save just the header to a file, set that to false.

An example function that would dump the response to a file could be:

```
import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
)

func dumpResponse(resp *http.Response, filename string) error {
    dump, err := httputil.DumpResponse(resp, true)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return ioutil.WriteFile(filename, dump, 0644)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following on the answer by @Riscie you could also pick up the headers from the response with something like this:

```
for header, values := range resp.Header {
    for _, value := range values {
        log.Printf("\t\t %s %s", header, value)
    }
}
```