# Is there a way to serialize golang http request object and persist in DB

Tags: http, go, serialization

I need to make a http call in golang code. My server code will create the http request object and put it in database.

The worker code will get the data from the DB and should be able to make the http call using the persisted request object.

Can I directly persist the request object in DB by serializing the http request or do I need to add method/URL/body separately in the database?

Comment: you're making a lot of questions at the same time, looks like you're learning Go, I recommend you taking the [tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) and/or take a look here: https://gobyexample.com/

Comment: Try it, and when you get stuck, come back here with a specific question. The answer to your question as currently posed is 'it depends'.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Write

Answer (score 5):

There's not a nice way to serialize the `http.Request` structure itself (see notes below), but you can serialize the request back into HTTP/1.1 wire format (and deserialize too).  This can be done using [`Request.Write`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Write) and [`http.ReadRequest`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ReadRequest):

```
func captureRequestData(req *http.Request) error {
    var b = &bytes.Buffer{} // holds serialized representation
    var tmp *http.Request
    var err error
    if err = req.Write(b); err != nil { // serialize request to HTTP/1.1 wire format
        return err
    }
    r := bufio.NewReader(b)
    if tmp, err = http.ReadRequest(r); err != nil { // deserialize request
        return err
    }
    *req = *tmp // replace original request structure
    return nil
}
```

Persistence of the serialized buffer is just a matter of saving a copy of `b`.  You might prefer to persist the `string` representation, which involves some additional conversions:

```
s := b.String() // persist this
r := bufio.NewReader(strings.NewReader(s))
```

---

There are a couple of reasons, at least, why you can't just use [`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) for this:

1. The [public fields of `Request`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) include *functions*, which Marshall does not accept:

   > json: unsupported type: func() (io.ReadCloser, error)
2. [`Request`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go) also contains a *private* field `ctx` which thwarts any generic attempts at deserialization:

   > ctx is either the client or server context. It should only
   >   be modified via copying the whole Request using WithContext.
   >   It is unexported to prevent people from using Context wrong
   >   and mutating the contexts held by callers of the same request.

Comment: BTW: `httputil.DumpRequest` and `Request.Write` likely have the same implementation under the hood -- so either could work for this, but the [`DumpRequest` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequest) says that it should only be used for debugging purposes.

Comment: Serializing the [`Response`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response) can be done using a nearly identical routine, with a small amount of substitution (`req`/`resp`, etc.).  [`http.ReadResponse`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ReadResponse) takes one additional argument, which can be `nil` (it doesn't seem to matter in my testing).

Comment: One liner to dump a complete request for debugging (warning: security issues): `fmt.Println("Request: ", string(assumeNoError(httputil.DumpRequest(request /*body*/, true)).([]byte)))`. Requires: [assumeNoError](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64346779/86967)

Comment: Related/opposite question: [Parse HTTP requests and responses from text file in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33963467/86967)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequest

```
import "net/http/httputil"

dumped, err := httputil.DumpRequest(req, true)
```

Comment: From the documentation: > it should only be used by servers to debug client requests.